# Implications of caching objects (per user) and garbage collection

Tags: c#, caching, garbage-collection

When you store something in ASP.NET's build in cache, how does this work with the garbage collector?

Example:

```
if( not in cache)
{
  List<UserSales> sales = SalesService.GetByUserId(loggedInUser.id);

  InsertToCache(cacheKey, sales);
}
else
{
   // loads from cache
}
```

So for each user, I first check if the data is in cache.

What I want to know is, what effect does this have on the garbage collector?  If the sales object has say 200-500 rows for some users, how will the GC behave in this situation?

What if I have a sliding expiration for 20 minutes so it is removed from the cache, just because it is removed, it still has to be GC'd correct?

The only thing holding a reference to sales would be the cache system, and the mvc view page but that goes out of scope when the requests ends.

Answer (score 0):

The cache will simply remove it's reference to the cached item when it expires.  If a reference is also held by a page that is running then the cache item will not be eligible for GC until the request ends.